# Entity framework foreign key id fields handling

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3

I'm using EF 4.3.1 with generated POCOs from EF DbContext Generator.

If I have for example the following relation of two objects:

```
class ClassA
{
  int Id
  ...
}

class ClassB
{
  int Id
  int ClassAId
  ClassA ClassA
  ...
}
```

Whats the best way to ensure the synchronization of ClassB's ClassAId and ClassA properties? This should also work if the POCO is not attached to a DbContext.

I was thinking of making both properties setters private and implement a setter by myself, but maybe there is a much better soluton which does not require manual modification / additions of the generated POCO classes?

Comment: If I'm not wrong : In your edmx, when setting a relation, you have a checkbox "Add Foreign Key  properties to the xxx entity"... UnCheck, and you won't have to think about that.